# Restoring data deleted from Directory Utility

Tags: macos, backup, restore, user-account, directory-utility

When trying to rearrange user accounts, I deleted some data using the Directory Utility (data on a user account under "Users" in the Node "Local/Default").

I would like to restore this data.

I have a Time Machine Backup available from before the change. What file would I need to look for to restore, or what other steps must I take?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `xar` archive of the directory `dslocal` made every Saturday by the launch daemon- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.var-db-dslocal-backup.plist`. You can find the archive here-

```
 /private/var/db/dslocal-backup.xar
```